# Keras Theano BackEnd

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, keras

im new to Keras in Python. I just created my first convolution neural network for number recognition using MNIST datasets. However, i got this warning message which i cannot figure out the solution.

> UserWarning: Method on_batch_end() is slow compared to the batch
>   update. Check your callbacks.

The full code is provided in this [link](http://pastebin.com/PjnRK1H2)

By the way, im using windows 10 and `python 2.7`. My `keras` version is 1.2.1 and `theano` is 0.8.2. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us information about the machine you use to your computations?

Comment: im sorry , i dont get it, what do you meant by information on machine use for computations?

Comment: The parameters of your computer / virtual machine where you are running your script.

Comment: nvidia geforce 710M, intel i5, theano is run on cpu not gpu...do you meant these?

Comment: When exactly this error is raised? In fit or evaluate method?

Comment: in fitting method

Comment: And what are the shapes of your dataset? Especially these which take part in a fitting?

Comment: for training, i used 50000 samples of images

Comment: for testing i used 10000 images

Comment: each image is 28*28 pixels of size

Comment: How long does your epoch last?

Comment: not even completing the first epoch, still trying to figure it out, currently trying to use Spyder, hope that solve my problems

Comment: Could you post the whole error message?

Comment: nevermind, solve it already, thank you

Comment: @xxl , thank you for your effort, i did solve it already, how did you set your keras to run on gpu, i tried before but it kept run on cpu, nevermind if you do not want to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code in my PC and get the result follow. using windows 10 and python 2.7. My keras version is 1.0.5 and theano is 0.8.2. 
warning dosen't appear, and no error you can ignore your warning I think.

---

1. C:\Anaconda\python.exe H:/keras-master/examples/download.py Using
   Theano backend.

   Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 745 (CNMeM is disabled, cuDNN 5103)
   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\cuda__init__.py:600:
   UserWarning: Your cuDNN version is more recent than the one Theano
   officially supports. If you see any problems, try updating Theano or
   downgrading cuDNN to version 5.   warnings.warn(warn) ('X_train
   shape:', (50000L, 1L, 28L, 28L)) (50000L, 'train samples') (10000L,
   'test samples')

Epoch 1/10 50000/50000 [==============================] - 44s -
    loss: 0.9157 - acc: 0.6879
Epoch 2/10 50000/50000
    [==============================] - 43s - loss: 0.3536 - acc: 0.8903

Epoch 3/10 50000/50000 [==============================] - 44s -
    loss: 0.3032 - acc: 0.9065
Epoch 4/10 50000/50000
    [==============================] - 44s - loss: 0.2753 - acc: 0.9150

Epoch 5/10 50000/50000 [==============================] - 43s -
    loss: 0.2526 - acc: 0.9203
Epoch 6/10 50000/50000
    [==============================] - 43s - loss: 0.2391 - acc: 0.9257

Epoch 7/10 50000/50000 [==============================] - 45s -
    loss: 0.2285 - acc: 0.9296
Epoch 8/10 50000/50000
    [==============================] - 43s - loss: 0.2155 - acc: 0.9322

Epoch 9/10 50000/50000 [==============================] - 43s -
    loss: 0.2104 - acc: 0.9347
Epoch 10/10 50000/50000
    [==============================] - 44s - loss: 0.1963 - acc: 0.9392

```
('Test score:', 0.1083350375296548) ('Test accuracy:',
0.96709999999999996) 4/4 [==============================] - 0s [2 1 0 4] [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]  [ 0.  1.  0.  0. 
0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]  [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1)

Change verbose to higher amount. Like 2 or more.

What verbose=1 does is printing a log line after every batch. Printing, itself is not an issue, but you don't want it to happen millions of times per second.

Your computer is simply not good enough for your code.

So yes, you can ignore this warning, or change verbose and get rid of it.